# Is there anything like Visio stencils in Rhapsody?

Tags: uml, rhapsody, stencils

In Visio, we can define custom stencils. In Rhapsody, can i define stencils like Visio? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Rhapsody lets you associate an image file with a model element. This image can then be used to represent the element in diagrams in place of the standard graphic representation.

Would this feature help you ?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB2MU_9.0.1/com.ibm.rhp.uml.diagrams.doc/topics/rhp_t_dm_associating_image_fl_mod_ele.html

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't want to change the standard image of the diagram element. I try to group only relevant diagram items like in stencils to reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is not. Since Rhapsody is a UML Tool the concept "Stencils" in Visio is not really relevant.

Walter